# How to load audio completely before playing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, audio

I have to load audio completely before playing it. Player should play audio automatically after loading it completely. There should not be pause button/user can not pause it. Here's my code, but unable to do so.

*Hyper Text Markup Language:*

```
<audio class="audio-player" onloadeddata="myOnLoadedData()" onprogress="myOnProgress()"  src="<?php echo $audio_link;?>" controls>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
function myOnLoadedData() {
    console.log('Loaded data'); 
    $('audio.audio-player').attr('autoplay','autoplay');
}
function myOnProgress(){
    console.log('downloading');
}
```

Or is there any other player that meets my requirement?

Comment: Have you tried to use `onload` event? I never used audio in `HTML5`, but I'll use and I made a function to load a array with game musics that I didn't tested so far.

Comment: Try `onloadeddata()`

Comment: already tried onloadeddata onloadedmetadata.First it must load complete audio and play it automatically

Comment: FYI, most mobile devices don't allow an audio file to be played without any user interaction

Comment: its not for mobile devices.i need it on pc

Comment: @NirojAdhikary `onloadeddata="this.play()"`???  http://jsfiddle.net/8bw6qwm3/  But not sure why you want it to be fully loaded before playing it

Answer (score 6):

Try using `XMLHttpRequest` to return `Blob` of audio file, `new Audio()` , `.load()` , `.play()`

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", "/path/to/audio/file/", true);
request.responseType = "blob";    
request.onload = function() {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    var audio = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(this.response));
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
  }
}
request.send();
```

Comment: This is the great way to do. You could also use status `500` above to detect if the response has timed out or if got error. `this.status>=500`.

Answer (score 0):

I used the method of @guest271314 to do a funtion that load every music link/URL that are in an object.

```
function LoadSounds(obj,ch,ca){
(function(r){
    var i,
    lo=0, // number of sounds loaded
    len=0, // number of sounds to load
    con={}; // an object with the sounds loaded
    for(i in obj){
        len++ // increase the number of sounds to load
    }
    for(i in obj){
        (function(i){
            r=0;
            r=new XMLHttpRequest();
            r.open("GET",obj[i],true);
            r.responseType="blob";
            r.onload=function(){
                if(this.status==200){
                    lo++
                    con[i]=new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(this.response));
                    con[i].load();
                    ch(obj[i]);
                    if(lo==len)ca(con)
                    r=undefined;
                }
            }
            r.send();
        })(i);
    }
    i=undefined;
})(0);
```

}

Compressed...!

```
function LoadSounds(n,o,e){!function(t){var i,s=0,d=0,u={};for(i in n)d++;for(i in n)!function(i){t=0,t=new XMLHttpRequest,t.open("GET",n[i],!0),t.responseType="blob",t.onload=function(){200==this.status&&(s++,u[i]=new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(this.response)),u[i].load(),o(n[i]),s==d&&e(u),t=void 0)},t.send()}(i);i=void 0}(0)}
```

Using example...!

```
// Note that these musics in my example aren't in a valid link
var MyMusics={
   Music1:'http://example.com/music.ogg',
   BestEver:'http://example.com/bestever.ogg'
};
LOAD_SOUNDS(
MyMusics, // Musics object
function(){alert("+1 loaded");}, // function when a link music is loaded
function(){e.BestEver.play();} // function when all musics from links were loaded
);
```