# Playing a blob in the audio element on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, audio

I have some code that works fine on the desktop in Chrome and Firefox, and now I'm trying to get it to work on Chrome in Android. I have created some audio in the browser and I'd like to present an audio control so that the user can click play. Here is the final look of the control:

```
<audio controls src="blob:https%3A//mydomain.com/5b7cbd96-b204-4b1c-8de3-9fb212c37928"></audio>
```

I tried playing a file from the browser with this:

```
<audio controls src="/sample.wav"></audio>
```

And that worked fine, so I know that the audio control can play WAV files.

The controls look different, too. The one that plays from the server contains the timing, that is, "0:00 / 1:23". The one that is created in JavaScript contains only "0:00". That leads me to believe that the control didn't actually load the audio in, but I have no idea why.

I printed out some debug info on the blob and I see the reported size is 184,440, and the reported type is "audio/wav".

The way I created the URL that I put in the audio's src is:

```
// dataView is of type DavaView, and contains the WAV.
var audioBlob = new Blob([dataView], { type: "audio/wav" });
var url = URL.createObjectURL(audioBlob);
```

How would I debug this further? Or is there another way to set up the audio control for Android?

Thanks!

**Update:**

I didn't solve this problem but I worked around it. Instead of using the `<audio>` control for playback, I am using an `AudioBuffer` directly:

```
var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
var audioBuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(1, sampleArray.length, audioCtx.sampleRate);
audioBuffer.copyToChannel(sampleArray);
source.buffer = audioBuffer;
source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
source.start();
```

Comment: Seems to be a bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=227476

Comment: Try using `new Audio()` with `objectURL` as parameter , calling `audio.load()` before `audio.play()` , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33755524/how-to-load-audio-completely-before-playing

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, Android Chrome cannot play audio from a blob. I came across this bug when I was implementing [Recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) to record audio on mobile browsers. In my research I came across a couple of issues reported to the chromium project.
[Issue 1](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=227476)
[Issue 2](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=531379)

Lucky for me, I was working on the [Recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) library because if I wasn't, It would have taken me a lot more than a 1 day to find a fix to this bug. Anyway, there was an [issue](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/issues/86) opened about this in the [Recorder.js](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs) git repository as well. @dokechin's answer in that thread worked for me. Thanks @dokechin!

Just convert your blob to base64 data and Android Chrome will play it.
You can do it like this,

```
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
      // e.targer.result will hold the base64 data.
      // Note: It includes the pre-text "data:audio/<format>;base64,<base64 data>"
      // Then do
      audio.src = e.target.result;
      // OR
      $("#your-audio-tag").attr("src", e.target.result);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```