# Chrome for Android bugs in replaying audio recording

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, audio, recorder.js

I'm using recorder.js to record audio on a web page and I would like to give the possibility to the user to play it back.
I have got a minimal testcase that works well with Chrome desktop but fails with Android. The recording seems ok. But the audio tag does not seem to be able to play the blob (on Android). 
https://www.quidoo.fr/html/test_recorder.html

```js
window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var audio_context;
var recorder;

function init_recording(){
 audio_context= new AudioContext();
 navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true},
  function (stream){
   var source=audio_context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
   recorder=new Recorder(source); // defined in recorder.js
  },
  function(error) {
     alert('No live audio input');
  }
 );
}

function onRecord(){
 recorder.clear(); 
 recorder.record();
}

function onStop(){
 recorder.stop();
 recorder.exportWAV(function(blob) {
     var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     var myAudio=window.document.getElementById('myAudio');
     myAudio.src=url;
 });
}

init_recording();
```

```html
<script src="https://www.quidoo.fr/js/libs/recorder.js"></script>
<button onclick="onRecord()">Record</button>
<button onclick="onStop()">Stop</button>
<audio id="myAudio" controls></audio>
```

I was wondering if it is a Chrome for Android bug or if I missed anything. Is there a way to bypass this without having to upload it before replaying it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are still having this issue, but I have found a couple of alternatives since this is a documented bug in Chrome on Android.

Edit:  I just found this answer as well. This is by far the easiest fix. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38591006/4601393

This alternative is not exactly user friendly, but if you go to chrome://flags on your mobile device and enable "enables the unified media pipeline on Android", the audio tag will successfully play the url (at least for me it did).
Source: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=253465

Another alternative is to generate the blob as a URL, use XHR to download the blob, generate a url for the downloaded blob, and use the last url in the audio source.  I haven't actually used this last method, but I have seen multiple users mention this way during my searches.

Source: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=227476 (Comment 21)

Hopefully a fix is implemented soon.